# How to correctly set display flex in this case

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using `display:flex;` on div which has let's say 3 divs inside it (could be more). These divs have width of 30% and also have set `min-width` to prevent too much shrinking (There's a text in this div so it has to be readable).

My goal is to achieve that, when there is no more space for all divs in one row, then break div which has no space to another row. I've achieved this with `flex-flow:row wrap;` but this is the place where the problem occurs.

[image]

As you can see, there's a big blank space between two divs in first row and third div is stuck to first div. I've tried to make space there with `margin-top`, but I want to achieve that the spaces between divs will be same (horizontally and vertically). Do you have any advice or should I just set some breakpoints with media queries for different width of divs depending on width of screen?

```css
.container{
  background-color:#eee;
  width:100%;
  height:100;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.card-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.card{
  background-color:#ccc;
  width:25%;
  max-width:300px;
  min-width:220px;
  padding:1em;
  margin:0em 1em;
  margin-top:2em;
}

.card h1{
  text-align:center;
}

.card p{
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="card-wrapper">
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 1 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
     
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 2 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
       
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 3 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to remove the `justify-content:space-between;` from your `.card-wrapper` class.

Answer (score 0):

How do you like this decision? Flex containers are evenly distributed depending on the screen size. In the css, I marked the edits.

```css
.container{
  background-color:#eee;
  width:100%;
  height:100;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.card-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  /*justify-content:space-between;*/
}

.card{
  background-color:#ccc;
  /*width:25%;*/
  /*max-width:300px;*/
  min-width:220px;
  padding:1em;
  margin:0em 1em;
  margin-top:2em;
  flex: 1; /*add this it*/
}

.card h1{
  text-align:center;
}

.card p{
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="card-wrapper">
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 1 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
     
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 2 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
       
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 3 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
     
  </div>
</div>
```

second:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let width_nth = $('.card').width();
  $('.card:nth-child(3)').css('flex' , 'unset');
  $('.card:nth-child(3)').css('width' , width_nth +'px');
});
```

```css
.container{
  background-color:#eee;
  width:100%;
  height:100;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.card-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  /*justify-content:space-between;*/
}

.card{
  background-color:#ccc;
  /*width:25%;*/
  /*max-width:300px;*/
  min-width:220px;
  padding:1em;
  margin:0em 1em;
  margin-top:2em;
  flex: 1; /*add this it*/
}

.card h1{
  text-align:center;
}

.card p{
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="card-wrapper">
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 1 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
     
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 2 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
       
     <div class="card">
       <h1>This is card 3 </h1>
       
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost ,we are slowly getting in here. If the card 3 didn't have full page width it will be it. Widths of card have to be same

Comment: I can offer one more solution where the width parameter is assigned to the third element. This works on page load `(document).ready`. But what you want to do, I advise you to implement using a `grid`.